# The use of **one-half**, vs **half**.

Tags: calculus, education

I don't know what category this would go in, so please help me with that.

Something I have noticed is that people use the word **one-half**, and **half** interchangeably.

Suppose you have 6 milk cartons.

One would say, **"I'll take half of those cartons**.

Suppose you have $50$$.

One would say, **Give me one-half of your money**.

Both of these words in the english language imply $50%$.
These words are used interchangeably, but doesn't **one-half** correspond to $1\frac{1}{2}$, which is clearly not half. Why is this, why do people use it interchangeably? (Please add a tag I don't know the right one).

Comment: The "one" specifies the number of halves. Two halves equals one whole. You can count how many halves: one half, two halves, three halves, etc. But one half is simply a half.

Comment: "One-half carton of milk" and "one-half _of your_ cartons of milk" are very different quantities.

Comment: The edit by @DavidG.Stork could potentially confuse things.  It is not clear that how it appears now is what is intended by the OP.  The values in the last paragraph used to be $50$ (*without the percent symbol*) and $1\frac{1}{2}$.  In any case, one of the key words to watch for here is "**of**".  If you have "*half* **of quantity c**" then we are referring to $\frac{c}{2}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz I agree. I was scratching my head because the question made no sense. I rolled it back to the original version.

Comment: I think this usage survives in American English, but not British English (OED's last citation of British source is dated 1823). Certainly I've only ever heard it from American sources.

Comment: There was a % sign within the context of two dollar signs (math context).  I was simply allowing what the author placed to be expressed.  But I have no problem with reverting to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "one-half" and "half" refer to $1/2=0.5$. To say $1\frac{1}{2}$, we would say either "one and a half" or "three halves."

Answer (score 0):

The issue is one of spoken English usage.

There are no formal written rules.

In general, you use the form "one half" when you want to be exact and accurate and to stress the precise value of a mathematical expression, but you say "a half" or "half of" in more casual speech and expressions.

Casual:
"Give me half a pound (or kilogram) of cheese, please."
"There's only about half a liter of gas (petrol) left in the motorscooter; I have to fill it up right away."
"Nearly half of the class were absent with flu yesterday."

Exact-mathematical-scientific
"The integral of x dx is one half x squared."
"Measure one half liter of water and place in your flask."
"The length of cloth needed for this pattern is one and one half meters."
"Find the length of time it will take for the population to reduce to one half of its original level.

Again these are not strict rules but matters of preferred usage.